# Search for a record from multiple tables in Room database

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

I have to search for a record from multiple tables, let's suppose I have multiple tables named as New arrival, Featured products, Hot products etc. I have to search for a product using its product Id first from New arrival table if record is found then stop searching else search from Featured table and so on.

Comment: make multiple query for multiple table and used if else then possiable

Comment: You'd better have one table for products with columns for marking a product as new, hot, ...